# laravel user only vote once in a form

Tags: php, laravel, vote

I have a question about an user vote system that I want to make.

Is it possible to make kind of role model in the users model, and that if the user has voted (it is a form that they fill in) they cannot view that page or cannot submit the form again because they already voted once.

But I am not sure if this is possible, do you know if there is a way to make this possible?

**Update**

Users Model:

```
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = ['email', 'password', 'voted'];

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
```

Option Model:

```
protected $table = 'options';

protected $fillable = ['id, points'];
```

User migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('voted')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Option Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('options', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('option');
        $table->tinyInteger('points');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Maybe good to know, in my RoundOneController@update I have 2 If else statements. 
(If select box 1 is id from database, then update, else make new one. Same for select box 2)
But if there is a possibility that when this has ended the users table will be updated and the voted column will change to 1, than the user cannot vote anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how your code is setup, there are in fact several ways to accomplish this.

One way would be to have a `voted` column in your `User` Model.  If you set it up as a `boolean` in your Migrations with a default value of 0,

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->boolean('voted')->default(0);
});
```

then you can just set it to '1' after a User votes.  Then set up `Middleware` for the voting page which checks for the presence of this value.

middleware file:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if (Auth::user()->voted) {
         return redirect('home');
     }

     return $next($request);
}
```

Make sure to register the Middleware in `kernal.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ......
    'voted' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfVoted::class,
];
```

and apply it to your route(s):

```
Route::get('user/vote', ['middleware' => ['voted'], function () {
    //
}]);
```

Comment: Aha okay, and than when the user has submitted the form, you change the boolean to an 1 with an if function?

Comment: @JeroenvanRooijen you would submit the `voteForm` to your Controller method, which would then store the value '1' for 'voted'.  i.e. `User::update([ 'voted' => 1 ])`

Comment: It havn't helped me yet. I updated my users migtrate, maked a middleware called, RedirectIfVoted and updated my kernal.php. I also maked a __construct and put this code in it `$this->middleware('voted');` But I don't know how to change the boolean in another controller with the store method (because I use that one for my form, and I am NOT using the UserController).

Comment: Which controller are you using for your form? And how are your models related to eachother?

Comment: My form is using the RoundOneController, and I have not related my models yet because it was not necessary. I will update my post and put the models and migrations in the first post

Comment: When a user votes and the fork is submitted to a controller, that Controller Method has to call Auth::user()->update(['voted'=>1]); or something like that depending how you retrieve your User Model

Comment: Thanks! The voted column has changed to 1. I cannot get the form page anymore. Thank you very much!